LightningChart JS - RactangleSeries cornerRadius - Rounded Corners
I'm using LightningChart JS to display live spectrogram using HeatmapScrollingGridSeriesIntensityValues.
I am drawing rectangles on the live heatmap using RectangleSeries, I want to make the rectangle corners round.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
